# Delay and cancel intermediate calls in SelectionChanged event

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous

I have a translator function for a selected text in a document. Translation took some seconds because it use a webservice. That works fine. I use for this an selection changed event.

```
Private Sub recDescrieri_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles recDescrieri.SelectionChanged
        Dim selection As DocumentRange = recDescrieri.Document.Selection
        'Dim selectedText As String = recDescrieri.Document.GetText(selection)
        If selection.Length = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        TRANSLATE_TEXT
End Sub
```

The problem is that, when I select the text in the recDescrieri document, the event is triggered for 4-5 succesive times. Because the TRANSLATE_TEXT took about 1-2 seconds, there is a long delay until the translated text is shown. In fact, selection changes very quickly and triggers the event.

I need to translate only the final selected text, not intermediate phases.
I think I have to use

```
Await Task.Delay
```

to cancel anterior phases when a new event is rised, since between anterior phases there is less then 500 ms.

How can I use Await Task.Delay to cancel intermediate phases, to not allowing them to call translate function, and to allow to call translate function only for the last phase of selection ?

Thank you !

Comment: Why do want to use `Task.Delay` specifically? I'd be using a `Timer` with an `Interval` of 500. Each time your event is raised, reset the `Timer` and then only make the call to your web service when the `Timer` `Ticks`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  No, I can use a timer. Thank you very much !